# Template class, static function compile error c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have the following function defined inside my linked list class.  The declaration in the header file looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
class RingBuffer
{
  ...//stuff
  static BLink * NewLink (const T&); // allocator
};
```

BLink is a "link" class within the RingBuffer class.  The following implementation code:

```
template <typename T>
RingBuffer<T>::BLink * RingBuffer<T>::NewLink( const T& t ) // this is line 114
{
  // create a new link in linked list
  ....
  ....
}
```

Is giving me this compile error:

./ringbuff.cpp:114: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before â*â token

I am stumped as to why it it needs an expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before the return value.

Comment: There is no return value in your excerpt and it's not clear which line is 114. Also, you're missing the semicolon after the `class` definition.

Comment: Are you trying to declare the template inside a function or other scope? (i.e. are you missing a close brace above it?)

Comment: line 114 is the line after "template <typename T>"

Comment: no I'm not trying to declare the template inside a function or other scope.  the return value I am aiming for, "BLink *", is a pointer to a class that is a sub-class of class RingBuffer

Comment: I'm trying to only disclose the code that should in theory be relevant to the function at hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that you are referring to a nested dependent type name (i.e. BLink is nested inside RingBuffer which is dependent on a template parameter)

You need to help your compiler a little in this case by stating that `RingBuffer<T>::BLink` is an actual type name. You do this by using the `typename` keyword.

```
template <typename T>
typename RingBuffer<T>::BLink * RingBuffer<T>::NewLink(const T& t)
{
  // ...
}
```

### Explanation:

The compiler cannot know if `RingBuffer<T>::BLink` is a type name or a static member until the template parameter `T` is known. When the compiler parses your function template `T` is not known and the rule to solve the ambiguity is to default to "this is not a type name".

Another short example (blatantly copied from Scott Meyers' Effective C++):

```
template<typename C>
void print2nd(const C& container)
{
  C::const_iterator * x;
  …
}
```

This maybe illustrates the problem a little better as it's more compact. As already said it's not clear for the parser whether C::const_iterator is a type name or a static data member as it doesn't know what `C` is when it parses this part of the code (it may know at a later point in time when the template is actually instantiated). So to ease the compiler implementers' lives this ambiguity is resolved to "not a type name" and if the programmer wants to use a type name which is nested inside anything that is dependent on a template parameter he/she has to use the `typename` keyword in front of the name to let the compiler know that it should be treated as a type name.

Unfortunately there is an exception to that rule regarding nested dependent type names when using them inside a base class list or the base class identifier in a member initialization list.

```
template<typename T>
struct Base {
  struct Nested {
    Nested(int) {}
  };
};

template<typename T>
struct Derived : public Base<T>::Nested { // typename not allowed here
  Derived(int i)
    : Base<T>::Nested(i) // nor here
  {}
};
```

Btw: You should set your console client's charset to UTF-8, so you get `‘*’` instead of `â*â`.

Answer (score 0):

compiler message is a little bit misleading.
In basically signifies syntax/parsing error.
Make sure the prototype is visible in compilation file, make sure you ring buffer is declared as template. and as other people have said, check the semi-column after class declaration.